# Object not found error although column is in the table (data.table format)

Tags: r, function

I have defined a following function:

```
counter<-function(data,varname){
  data[is.na(varname),.N]
}
```

When I pass the arguments:

```
counter(df,ip_address_ts)
```

I get the error:

```
Error in .checkTypos(e, names_x) : Object 'ip_address_ts' not found. Perhaps you intended ip_address_ts, email_address_ts
```

ip_address_ts is in df, so why does this not work?

Comment: Please read the information at the top of the [tag:r] tag page regarding asking questions.  In particular code should be complete and self contained.  The input and library statements are missing so no one except you can run it.

Comment: Since your question is not reproducible, I'll guess: you have an object named `df` that is presumably a `data.frame`, and within it is a column named `ip_address_ts`. If that's true, then you are asking for "non-standard evaluation" (NSE), which can be fragile if you are not very comfortable in the language. I suggest keeping it simple, `function(data, varname) data[ is.na(data[[varname]]), ]`; next you need to resolve where `.N` is defined and how it should be used in the context of `df`.

Answer (score 1):

Your code is looking the object `ip_address_ts`, not the string `"ip_address_ts"`

```
counter(df, "ip_address_ts")
```

Comment: The input to data[is.na(varname),.N], for example df[is.na(ip_address_ts),.N] is a column name that is not a string. If I pass column name as string, I won't get the desired output. I will get 0 instead of 5000.

Answer (score 0):

Solution is to use get and then pass the column name as string:

```
counter<-function(data,varname){
  data[is.na(get(varname)),.N]
}
  

counter(df,"ip_address_ts")
```

For this and other tips check out this link:

http://brooksandrew.github.io/simpleblog/articles/advanced-data-table/#3-functions

Answer (score 0):

I happened to encounter the same error  while working in R Studio, having checked the column exists in the data frame. Two things helped:

1. Restarting the session
2. Installing and loading the right package before running the code (In my case it
   was the *'dplyr'* package in order to use the *filter()* function).

I hope this helps